# Riemann zeta function zeros notation

Tags: riemann-zeta, zeta-functions, riemann-hypothesis

In books/papers, we often see the notation that the zeros of the $\zeta$-function with positive imaginary part are denoted $\rho_n$ in order of increasing height.

However, because of the equation $\zeta(\bar{s})=\overline{\zeta(s)}$ and the functional equation it is easy to see that any zeros off the critical line in the critical strip occur in pairs, symmetric about the critical line.

So why are zeros denoted this way when there may be zeros with the same imaginary part?

Comment: Why does no one specify to only consider zeros in $0< Re(s) \leqslant 1/2$ to avoid this?

Comment: So far as I know, it's because many discussions in which that notation is used assume RH... so there'd be no advantage to allowing for phenomena which are presumed not to occur. But I'm not a specialist, so I really cannot say for sure...

Comment: Also, "explicit formulas" do refer to _all_ the zeros...